# Easy to add code like on piazza

Tags: feature-request

Isn't possible to update how the code is added to a question.

On piazza.com this is way simpler:

snapshot from piazza:

[image]

Comment: Other than that the button on SO is an icon, not text, how is it different?

Comment: considering our editor is just a textarea, no, this wouldn't be possible without replacing our entire editor.

Comment: Having a grey box being displayed, which doesn't change your input at all, is easier how? Maybe it looks a little nicer while you're typing, but I see no evidence to back up the claim that it would be easier.

Comment: It provides you with an space for the code, no need to add spaces to define it as code.You just copy paste, simple.

Comment: Same functionality is available with the `{}` button. Try it.

Comment: when using { } button, you can add only one line of code, on piazza you can add it all on one step.

Comment: I guess this is just asking for a wysiwyg editor, which is a reasonable request. You can select and add multiple lines of code at once on SO, though.

Comment: @StephanGheorghica did you try writing/pasting your code, selecting it all and then pressing the {} button?

Comment: Paste the code, select the code, and then click on the button.

Comment: @StephanGheorghica So what happened when  you tried to add multiple lines of code?

Comment: @RobertLongson : Now I got it, thanks. This will do.

Comment: I like how that site has an icon on most buttons, but for code they just threw in the towel and used a textual label :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar function can be obtain by pasting your code, selecting it all and then press the {} button